# TrayIcon right click event

Tags: delphi, system-tray, trayicon, tray

I'm using a TTrayicon in Delphi XE2, and I was wondering if there is any way to control a right click event.
I've tried with the click event, but I couldn't

Comment: The code for `TTrayIcon` makes me sad. All those idiotic calls to `GetCursorPos`. It really looks as though large parts of the VCL have been written by people that don't understand input messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign event handler to **OnMouseUp**. Use **Button** parameter to find out which button was pressed.

Comment: Both OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp can be used, but you are right. If you use OnMouseUp, tray icon will behave exactly as standard Windows tray icons (volume, network, etc...). I will edit answer right away.

Comment: This is the right answer to the question as asked. However, if you want to show a popup menu, then Polymorphin is accurate. If you are doing other than showing a popup menu in response to right click, you are probably doing something wrong. Note that the `OnMouseUp` event will fire even if the user attempts to right click using the keyboard. Which is down to a limitation in the original design of the shell API on which `TTrayIcon` stands.

Answer (score 1):

Associate a `TPopupMenu` to the TrayIcon.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkEvb.png]

Comment: How do you know the question is about popup menu ? There is no single mention of it in the question. @Polymorphin, just a hint, if you link the image this way `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` it will make the image *"clickable"* ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just think that he wants to know how to click on a trayicon associate a event and the popupmenu is the easiest way to to this.